# How to identify the pdf object in raw pdf file?

Tags: pdf

I want to remove certain objects using programs.

Using cpdf I can get the objects, if I can somehow identify the objects that I want to delete, then I should be able to modify pdf files with programs.

```
$ cpdf in.pdf -output-json -output-json-parse-content-streams -o out.json
$ cpdf -j out.json -o out.pdf
```

However, I can not find out the object corresponding to my target text. For example, text search does not work on a raw pdf file. What is the best way to identify the target object of a text?

EDIT: Here is a test pdf. Please remove XYZ from the top of each page. Note that the test is a significant simplification of the real pdf file. So the solution should not be so simple so that it can not be applied to real complicated pdf files.

```
curl -s https://i.stack.imgur.com/whsnm.gif | tail -c +43 > test.pdf
```

Comment: Could you show me how to use cpdf, qpdf, mupdf and pdftk to find objects corresponding to text respective as answers? I am not familiar with them on finding objs from texts.

Comment: For my case, the same text should have been added in the same way, as they were added by a program.

Comment: qpdf manual is quite long, I am not sure specifically what I should focus on. Could you please show me the specific point of reference for solving my problem?

Comment: I added a test case. See if it works.

Comment: I understand that this stripped file is likely not the same as the original. Could you at least show me how to deal with this file? The tricks demonstrated in this process may be useful in dealing with the real file.

Answer (score 0):

The output of `cpdf -output-json -output-json-parse-content-streams` may or may not contain text which is recognisable to you. This depends on the font encodings in use, and the way in which text is layed out. In your file, for example, the painting of the string "XYZ" is represented as

```
[ "\u0000;\u0000<\u0000=", "Tj" ]
```

This is a string representing three codepoints indexing into the font. Cpdf presently has no way to show you what actual text this corresponds to; a future version will.

So I don't think your task can be done via `cpdf -output-json` in the general case, or indeed in this specific case.

Comment: How do you know "\u0000;\u0000<\u0000=" correspond to XYZ? Where are index table of XYZ? Also, what is "\u0000;"? Since the ASCII code of ':' is 0x3b, is "\u0000;" just 0x00003b? If so why not just write it as 0x0003b in the cpdf output?

Comment: The string is stored in the JSON file by representing each byte of the PDF string directly. The PDF string is probably indexing into a font with two-byte character codes, which is why every other one is zero. I know this string represents XYZ simply because it is the only text string of length three in the file. The table from these codes to XYZ is in the PDF font object, elsewhere in the file. In some files, that object might not even tell you enough information to reconstruct the string. Short answer: PDF is complicated, mostly for good reason.

Comment: So then for complicated pdf files with hundred of pages. This trick will not be helpful? Is there some pdf viewer that allow users to highlight some text then show the underlying pdf code?